# Typescript: readonly property in class cannot be accessed

Tags: typescript, tsc

```
export declare class Config {
    readonly ROUTE_TYPE_CREATE: string;
}
```

---

```
import { Config } from "./Config";

export default class NewComponent {
    constructor() {
        this.routeType = Config.ROUTE_TYPE_CREATE;
    }
}
```

When I compile code, it returns:

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./new.cpn.ts:12:33 
    TS2339: Property 'ROUTE_TYPE_CREATE' does not exist on type 'typeof Config'.
```

What is the problem? Why is it unaccessible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declared an instance property on `Config`, but not a static property named `Config.ROUTE_TYPE_CREATE`. Add `static` and it should work:

```
declare class Config {
    static readonly ROUTE_TYPE_CREATE: string; 
}
```

The error message hints at this, if you read it *very* carefully:

> Property 'ROUTE_TYPE_CREATE' does not exist on type '**typeof Config**'.

If you had an instance, that would read `on type 'Config'`, but you're working with the class directly.